# How to not hard-code a file path

Tags: java, javafx, filepath, hardcoded

I'd like to calculate the path of a file placed into Source Packages using this implementation:

```
URL pathSource = this.getClass().getResource("saveItem.xml");
```

When I try to create a new File like the code below:

```
File xmlFile = new File(pathSource.toString());
```

And I try to use it to create a document like this:

```
Document document = builder.parse(xmlFile);
```

This give me the *java.io.FileNotFoundException*.
How can I calculate the file path without hard-coding?

**PS:** I already used pathSource.getPath() but it doesn't work either.
I would like to use a similar implementation:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

**PPS:** The structure is the following:
[image]

Comment: You are running this from a jar or from the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access a resource that inside a JAR file as a `File` instance. You can only get an `InputStream` to it.

As such, the following line

```
File xmlFile = new File(pathSource.toString());
```

won't work properly and when an attempt is made to read it later, a `FileNotFoundException` will be thrown.

Assuming you're trying to parse a XML file using `DocumentBuilder`, you can use the [`parse(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse-java.io.InputStream-) method:

```
try (InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("saveItem.xml")) {
    Document document = builder.parse(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - saveItem.xml is not in the classpath. 
If it is a web application, then file may be added to WEB-INF/classes folder.

Edit:
Try `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
getClass().getResource("saveItem.xml");
```

looks for the file in the same package (which are directories when you look at the file system) as the class that `getClass()` returns.

Make sure the file is in there. Also make sure it's really in there when you run your code, there's a difference between your source folder and the `target` or `bin` folder where the compiled class files are placed.

Also check what `pathSource.toString()` contains.